# Glitchy behavior with JQuery Draggable (fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use Jquery Draggable but I notice a flicker when the target item is lifted and then dropped, hovered over its old position, or brought out of its container.  The image in the dragged div just disappears or appears in the wrong spot (it's supposed to always be displayed in the same position while dragging - as you'd expect).

Any idea how this can be corrected?

My code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/28/

```
$(function () {
            $('#container').isotope({
                // options
                itemSelector: '.study-box',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
        });

        $(function () {
            $(".study-box").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: function () {
                    // We removeAttr('style') to get rid of the transform css that isotope added.
                    return $(this).clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass('isotope-item').addClass('drag-helper').appendTo('body');
                },
                start: function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                },
                stop: function () {
                    $(this).show();
                },
                zIndex: 100
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $(".folder-box").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
            $(".folder-box").droppable({
                // revert: "invalid",
                accept: ".folder-box, .set-box", 
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    //ui.draggable.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass('.folder-box').appendTo($this);
                    $('#container').isotope('remove', ui.draggable);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the JavaScript, just remove all "position:fixed" from the CSS. It is messing the correct display off the background position.